# Must declare the scalar variable "@s"

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
CmdString = "SELECT s.TotallBill - s.Advance - SUM(iph.Amount) AS RemainingBalance FROM SalesInvoice s INNER JOIN InstallmentPaymentHistory iph ON iph.SalesInvoiceId = s.SalesInvoiceID WHERE  [s.SalesInvoiceID] = @s.SalesInvoiceID";

try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesInvoiceID", txtSIN2.Text);

    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("SalesInvoice");
        sda.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            txtBalance2.Text = (dr["RemainingBalance"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
}
```

I get the error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@s"

In a textbox I am taking the value of `s.SalesInvoiceID`. How can I fix the error? Please answer me the correct query

Comment: Replace `where [s.SalesInvoiceID]=@s.SalesInvoiceID` with `where [s.SalesInvoiceID]=@SalesInvoiceID`

Comment: @  JohnLBevan  Now gets the Error   "Must declare the scalar variable "@SalesInvoiceID"

Comment: You are trying to select data based on an invoice ID saved in a variable named `@SalesInvoiceID`, but that variable has not been declared anywhere nor has it had a value assigned to it. When you set the CmdString you need to put into the string the actual id of the invoice you are looking for, not a variable name. I think your code should say `...where [s,SalesInvoiceID]=' + SalesInvoiceId (or whatever variable in your C# program has the ID to be found)

Comment: @JohnRC No, you should never concatenate SQL statements. You risk SQL injection. The OP has correctly used Parameters only did not get the name to match.

Comment: Some unrelated tips: `SqlCommand` is `IDisposable` so should be in a `using` block. You may want to take a look at [Can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). If this is English, `Totall` should only have one `l`.

Comment: You need to declare it first.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what the intent is but your Select statement is missing a Group by or Over clause to go with the Sum. Also, your parameter name in your Select must match the name you use in the Parameters.AddWithValue. Maybe something like this.

```
"SELECT 
s.SalesInvoideID
s.TotallBill, 
s.Advance, 
sum(iph.Amount) as RemainingBalance 
from SalesInvoice s 
inner join InstallmentPaymentHistory iph 
on 
s.SalesInvoiceID =iph.SalesInvoiceId
where 
[s.SalesInvoiceID]=@SalesInvoiceID"
Group By s.SalesInvoiceID;"
```

The join looked backwards to me. I am not the best at Transact SQL but I think Inner is really a Left join or just Join and s.SalesInvoiceID belongs on the left.